# Angular2 Webpack can't find name "Bloodhound"

Tags: angular, webpack, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm using [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) as a component for my Angular 2 project. I can use jQuery directly after did import but Bloodhound can't. The Typescript compiler said: "Cannot find name 'Bloodhound' "

I have loaded required libraries from `node_modules/` like this:

**baBootstrapTags.loader.ts**

```
// require('style-loader!bootstrap-css/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
require('style-loader!bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css')
require('style-loader!bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput-typeahead.css')
require('bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.js');

require('typeahead.js');
require('typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.bundle.min.js'); //<-- It's already contain Bloodhound define.
```

**baBootStrapTags.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Input} from '@angular/core';

import './baBootStrapTags.loader.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'ba-tags-input',
  template: require('./baBootStrapTags.html'),
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class BaBootStrapTags implements OnInit {
  cities: Bloodhound; // <----- ERROR HERE
  @Input() config:Object = {
    itemValue: 'value',
    itemText: 'text',
    typeaheadjs: {
      name: 'cities',
      displayKey: 'text',
      source: this.cities.ttAdapter()
    }
  };
}
```

Has anyone ever used Bloodhound (Typeahead) in Angular2? How do I declare new Object from external libraries?

Comment: You'll still need to import that name to use it locally.

Comment: Sorry but how to do that? Import {Bloodhound} from 'Typeahead.js' ?

Comment: You could try https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead instead that offers native Angular 2 functionality close to the one provided by Typeahead.js. It is super-flexible and has a simpler & more powerful API (RxJS-based) as compared to Bloodhound

Comment: Ya, i think so, but I don't know how to replace typeahead by RxJS in Bootstrap Tags Input T.T